# DLL load failed while importing pycbc_core while importing Clusters in Couchbase DB

Tags: python, couchbase

I have installed `couchbase` Python SDK using `pip install couchbase`. Following its tutorial [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html), after importing the following modules:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

# needed for any cluster connection
from couchbase.auth import PasswordAuthenticator
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
# needed for options -- cluster, timeout, SQL++ (N1QL) query, etc.
from couchbase.options import (ClusterOptions, ClusterTimeoutOptions,
                               QueryOptions)
```

I got the following error while importing `Cluster`:

```bash
>>> from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Path\To\Python\Env\lib\site-packages\couchbase\cluster.py", line 24, in <module>
    from couchbase.analytics import AnalyticsQuery, AnalyticsRequest
  File "Path\To\Python\Env\lib\site-packages\couchbase\analytics.py", line 16, in <module>
    from couchbase.exceptions import (PYCBC_ERROR_MAP,
  File "Path\To\Python\Env\lib\site-packages\couchbase\exceptions.py", line 28, in <module>
    from couchbase.pycbc_core import exception
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pycbc_core: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem. Did you solve this?